# O que é o ponto de interrogação em uma query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, prepared-statement

Usar `?` em uma *query* realmente evita o *SQL injection*? Evita 100%? Vi este código e ouvi muitas pessoas falando sobre isso, dizendo que ajuda neste caso e como usar? Alguém poderia dar um exemplo melhor?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE username = ? OR username = ?";
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Este é um *placeholder* para uma consulta parametrizada (*parameterized query*).

É um parâmetro anônimo para a *query*. **Ele é usado para evitar [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101) mesmo, mas não só**. Com ele não dá para injetar partes de uma *query* dentro da sua *query*.

Seria algo como usar `"SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE username = $par1 OR username = $par2"` mas tem a vantagem que é controlado pelo banco de dados através da API do PHP ao invés de puramente pelo PHP, portanto é bem mais seguro. O banco de dados terá a *query* pronta esperando o parâmetro. Não é uma *string* com a *query*. O *SQL injection* ocorre por causa da manipulação de *strings* que, por acaso, contém *queries*.

Uma das formas de usar seria:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE username = ? OR username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $userName, $userName);
```

Desta forma há a vinculação da variável $userName do PHP para os dois parâmetros que a *query* SQL está esperando.

**Este é um recurso disponível no banco de dados**. Isto é chamado de *prepared query*. **Originalmente é usado para agilizar a execução da *query***. Com ele uma *query* é *cacheada* pelo planejador do banco de dados permitindo algumas otimizações já que apenas os parâmetros são diferentes mas a execução segue o mesmo esquema sempre. Em alguns casos o ganho pode ser considerável.

Como consequência você ganha uma segurança maior contra *SQL injection*. Mas é importante notar que a segurança vem mais por um efeito colateral do recurso. Você evita que algo assim possa acontecer sem o programador perceber:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE username = $userName";
```

Suponha que alguém digite e `$userName` receba `"" OR 1 = 1; DROP TABLE tabela;`. Pronto, sua tabela foi para o espaço.

Este recurso de *prepared query* é disponibilizado pela API [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) do PHP e é usado da forma indica acima.

Usei o exemplo do MySQL que é o banco de dados mais usado com PHP mas pode ser usado com qualquer outro banco de dados que forneça alguma forma de "consultas preparadas". Portanto não precisa usar apenas a `mysqli`. Se o banco de dados e a API do PHP que faz o acesso fornecerem o recurso, é possível usá-lo de forma padronizada. Portanto não é algo que o PHP faz por você, isto vem do banco de dados.

Só para complementar:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE username = :user OR username = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $userName);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/QuerySyntax2.php).

Isto é o [PDO](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php) onde você tem mais controle como o parâmetro é usado, você coloca mais significado do que está passando e onde ele é usado. Não estou dizendo que o PDO é necessariamente melhor. Em alguns casos a sintaxe pode ser um pouco diferente.

[Referência](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements).

[Sintaxe do SQL do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) se for usar o recurso independente do PHP ou quiser entender melhor o recurso.

Comment: Interessante, não sabia desta questão de ser o banco de dados, ao invés do php.Também não sabia que agilizava a execução da query...

Comment: Me surgiu uma outra dúvida, mas vou colocar como pergunta, se der me responde lá também. Cara estou gostando disso. Receber conhecimento é algo impolgante. Valeu ai bigown!

Comment: Se não for relacionado, é melhor outra pergunta mesmo. Se eu souber e tiver tempo, eu respondo. Eu ainda vou melhorar algumas coisas na pergunta, mas vou fazer com calma agora.

Comment: Se vale a sugestão, tecnicamente *paramterized query* é a técnica em si, a interrogação é um simples *placeholder*

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Boa, fica melhor assim mesmo, editado. O crédito é seu.

Comment: *Oh! Stop it you...* :p

Answer (score 3):

Problemas de injeção de código podem ocorrer sempre que você mistura duas linguagens separadas. Por exemplo, bugs de injeção de SQL ocorrem quando tratamos dados do usuário como código SQL e passamos para o banco de dados executar e defeitos de XSS (cross site scripting) surgem quando pegamos texto do usuário e passamos para o browser como se fosse HTML (e esse HTML pode conter tags script).

Num mundo ideal, ao invés de usar strings pra representar tanto a query quanto os dados do usuário (permitindo que dados e código sql sejam concatenados/interpolados de forma perigosa) usaríamos tipos separados para esses valores que proibissem misturar um com o outro.

Tudo bem, mas então, como programar para evitar problemas com injeção?

Uma primeira alternativa é oferecer uma função de "escape", que converta dados do usuário em código seguro. Por exemplo, em HTML convertemos todos os `&` em `&amp;` e em SQL protegemos as aspas. Usar uma função de escapa é uma abordagem bastante simples e comum mas você tem que ter cuidado para não escapar algo duas vezes sem querer, já que essa operação normalmente não é não é idempotente.

A segunda alternativa no caso do SQL é parametrizar a query. Ao invés de sair concatenando as coisas na mão você diz (com os `?` ou alguma sintaxe similar) onde estão as "lacunas" da query e o próprio banco preenche essas lacunas com os parâmetros, que são passados separadamente. Como os dados do usuário são passados para o banco como parâmetros, não há risco deles serem executados como código SQL.