# Usar prepare statement em um valor de constante?

Tags: sql, pdo, prepared-statement

```
$type = 'post';
$stmtPG = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = :type");
$stmtPG->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmtPG->execute();
$total = $stmtPG->fetchColumn();
$total_paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
```

Há um tempo atras eu vi em uma pergunta aqui do stackoverflow que um cara falou que não precisa preparar valores de constantes, eu também tinha dado uma pesquisada no google sobre `prepared statement`, mas eu não entendi direito.

Como esse codigo deveria ser?

Edit:

```
$stmtPG = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = 'post'");
$total = $stmtPG->fetchColumn();
$total_paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
```

Comment: Basicamente uma constante é um valor que não muda, se você sabe qual é o valor inicial dela não tem o porque de escapa-la, agora se o valor dela é dinâmico (vem da entrada do usuário) é necessário assim como todas as outras entradas. Lembre, **nunca confie nos dados do seu cliente**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prepared Statement**

De forma resumida: você estará `preparando`sua `query` de forma protegida para evitar ataques como o [sql injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e também ganhará mais performance na execução da consulta.

Devemos sempre proteger os dados que vem do `front`, ou seja, que são enviados pelo usuário. No seu caso, a variável que faz parte da consulta já está diretamente no código, então não é necessário realizar a preparação (a menos que o valor da variável seja malicioso. Qual desenvolvedor faria isso?).

Nesse caso, sua consulta poderia ficar assim:

```
$type = 'post';
$stmtPG = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = " .$type);    
$total = $stmtPG->fetchColumn();
$total_paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
```

Caso o valor da variável `$type` viesse de fora, por exemplo, de um `POST = $_POST['tipo']`, a `preparação` da consulta seria de extrema importância.

**Aqui deixo algumas referências para estudo:**

[Sql Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

[Como acontece um SQL injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/103661)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)

[Artigo sobre Prepared Statements](http://blog.lucasrenan.com/prepared-statements-mysql/)

Comment: Com o código que você me mostrou está aparecendo um erro dizendo que a coluna `post` não existe. No meu caso `post` é o valor da coluna `entry_type`. Eu tentei fazer de outro jeito aqui, olha o meu edit da questão.

Comment: Evitar SQL Injection é uma das vantagens de usar Prepared Statement, mas não é só pra isso quer serve, ele também aumenta a performance de consultas repetidas

Comment: @Susi editei a resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam realmente, esqueci de acrescentar essa informação.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Uma duvida, qual a necessidade de colocar uma variável no valor de `entry_type = '$type'`?

Comment: @Susi, coloquei como variável pois no seu exemplo o valor está armazenado na variável, mas poderia colocar diretamente na query.

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do principio que você sabe o que é [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22621)

Primeiro precisa entender uma coisa, o Prepared Statement tem duas funcionalidades:

- Escapar valores (se bem utilizado)
- Otimizar buscas repetidas

Então você deve usa-lo sempre que possível, não necessariamente pela primeira mas pela segunda. Agora se você irá passar os valores pelo `bindParam` depende se você sabe que valor é esse, e não se o valor é ou não uma constante

Por exemplo imagina que você possui uma classe que faz algumas consultas com paginação:

```
class Paginacao {
    private $itensPorPagina;

    public function __construct($itensPorPagina) {
        $this->itensPorPagina = $itensPorPagina;
    }

    public function buscarPorNome($nome) {
        $stmtPG = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = :nome LIMIT $this->itensPorPagina");
        $stmtPG->bindParam(':nome', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //...
    }

    public function buscarPorTelefone($telefone) {
        $stmtPG = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE telefone = :telefone LIMIT $this->itensPorPagina");
        $stmtPG->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //...
    }
}
```

Então você usaria dessa forma

```
$paginacao = new Paginacao(25);

$paginacao->buscarPorNome($_GET["nome"]);
```

Observe que `itensPorPagina` não é uma constante, mas quem define seu valor é o programador na hora de instanciar a classe `Paginacao`

Você não precisa passar o `itensPorPagina` por `bindValue` porque você sabe que o valor dele é apenas um inteiro de valor 25, o fato de ser uma constante não tem nada a ver

Agora se fosse uma variável que viesse do usuário, como o nome e telefone, então sim, você precisa passar por `bindParam` para evitar SQL Injection

**Conclusão**

Você não precisa passar variáveis como parâmetro em instruções SQL se você sabe qual é o seu valor. Só passe aquilo que é duvidoso (entradas do usuário)

Comment: Mas porque você usou um named paramter no valor de `nome`? ":nome". Pelo que eu entendi o valor de `nome` não iria vir do usuário, então não sei porque você colocou ele no `bindParam`. PS: Eu não costumo usar o `bindParam` e menos ainda em uma `function` então eu posso estar falando besteira.

Comment: Pelo contrário, nome virá da entrada do usuário, atualizei a pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro

Answer (score 1):

É preciso levar em conta que *Prepared Statements* não servem exclusivamente para evitar *SQL Injection*, a outra grande vantagem é que o SGBD faz cache do *Statement* para que não precise compilar novamente uma query igual.

Dito isso, eu usaria `bindParam` mesmo que o valor seja uma constante pois as queries:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = 'post';
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE entry_type = 'page';
```

Teoricamente seriam compiladas duas vezes pelo servidor, onde uma *Prepared Statement* só seria compilada uma vez e o cliente apenas enviaria os parâmetros para o servidor.